# Proof about that operator is self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

In Linear Algebra:

Suppose I have a matrix $A$ that represents the linear product (the Gramian matrix)
Suppose I have a matrix $B$ that represents a linear transformation from Vector Space $V$ to itself.

I'm trying to prove that $T$ cannot be self adjoint.
I'm reading through this explanation but cannot seem to understand the logic behind the second last step. Why would $B^TA = AB$ ?

Why is this true:

If $\langle T(\mathbb{E}x), \mathbb{E}y \rangle = \langle \mathbb{E}x, T(\mathbb{E}y)\rangle \implies x^T(B^TA)y = x^T(AB)y$

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: " **The** linear transformation from V to itself", you wrote in line second. **What** lin. trasnformation from V to itself? There usually are lots of them... Then you talk of a "T": what is this?

Comment: sorry about that, meant "A" linear transformation, Updated the question though. thanks!

Comment: @vondip: I have tried to improve the look of your question, but you might want to check to see that I did not mess anything up. It has been suggested that you might want to look at the [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) and the [FAQ about how to ask questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from $$
  x^T (B^TA) y = x^T (AB) y \quad\text{for all $x,y$.}
$$

Assume that $B^TA \neq A B$. Then there'd be a vector $y$ with $B^TAy \neq ABy$. Let $y_1 := B^TAy$ and $y_2 := ABy$. Now, since $y_1 \neq y_2$ you can find an $x$ such that $x^T y_1 \neq x^Ty_2$. But then you'd have $$
  x^T(B^TA)y \neq x^T(AB)y
$$
which contradicts the initial assumption.

Comment: Hi fgp, I've edited my question as it wasn't clear enough. I was referring to another line I didn't quite understand 
Why is this true:

If <T(Ex), Ey> = <Ex, T(Ey)> ==> Xt(BtA)y = Xt(AB)y

Comment: @vondip It wasn't unclear, it was totally missleading! If you ask an explanation of the *last* line while you actually want one for *second to last line*, that's just wasting the time of anyone who answers. Especially if you explicitly state "Why would B transposed A = AB"! Why should anyone spend *their* time to answer *your* question if you don't even bother to ask your *actual* question?

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry, in my mind the line I was referring to what the most important and problematic part of the text. I've been struggling with it for the last 4 hours, and was more or less the last line I've paid attention to in the text. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @vondip You need to use that $(Bx)^T = x^TB^T$.

Comment: how does it take this assumption into account though ? <T(Ex), Ey> = <Ex, T(Ey)>

Comment: You *first* expand $T(\mathbb{E}x)$ (I find that notation a bit strange, btw). Then you use the identity I posted to rewrite the left side. And finally you expand the inner product.

Comment: By expanding T(x) do you mean to divide Ex based on the new base?

Comment: @vondip Quite frankly, I think you need to brush up your knowledge of linear operators on finite-dimensional spaces. $T$ is such a linear operator, hence (once you pick a fixed basis), it's defined by a matrix, $B$ in your case. The image of a vector $x$ is then $Bx$ (assuming that $x$ is expressed in terms of that fixed bases). That whole $\mathbb{E}$-business is supposed to express that dependency on a basis, though IMHO it creates more confusion than it avoids. There's only one basis here anyway, just think of vectors as $n$-tuples here...